# Generalizations of Directly Similar Theorem?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, plane-geometry

There is [an attractive theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremofDirectlySimilarFigures.html) that says that if two plane figures
are *[directly simila](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Similar.html)r*, then so is any convex combination of them.
Below, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are directly similar polygons: they have
the same angles in the same sequence;
They are (positively) scaled, rotated, translated versions of one another.
The convex combination
illustrated $P_{12} = \frac{1}{3} P_1 + \frac{2}{3} P_2$ is
also directly similar.

   [image: DirectlySimilar]
(Let me henceforth abbreviate "direcly similar" with "similar.")
My question is:

> **Q1**.
>   Is there a natural extension to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and to higher
>   dimensions?

Any extension cannot be an *exact* extension—some aspect has to give.
For example, here are two cubes $P_1$ and $P_2$, the latter
a $\frac{3}{4}$-scale rotated version of $P_1$.
Shown is $P_{12} = \frac{1}{2} P_1 + \frac{1}{2} P_2$,
and it is clearly not a cube. 
I would define similarity in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to require all faces to
be similar with the same scale factor as well preserving all
dihedral angles—in other words, $B$ is similar to $A$ if
$B$ is a rotated, scaled, translated version of $A$.

   [image: SimilarNotCube]
But perhaps this is true?

> **Q2**.
>   Is the convex combination of two cubes (scaled, rotated,
>   translated) always a parallelopiped?
>   A parallelotope in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Another approach would be to restrict the transformations:

> **Q3**. Is there some condition on the transformations
>   applied to the shapes that permits the similarity conclusion?
>   Or: What is the widest class of transformations that leads
>   to the similarity conclusion?

Certainly if $P_2$ is just a translated, scaled copy of $P_1$,
then any convex combination is similar, in any dimension.
Rotations are the culprit. But perhaps some rotations still
lead to similarity.

It seems likely this has all been well-explored.
If so, thanks for pointers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, we may forget about translations, since they just shift the convex combinations. Thus we may regard the direct similarity as a linear transform given by an orthogonal matrix $A$ multiplied by some constant $\alpha$. Then the transform mapping the otiginal polytope to the convex combination is given by 
$$
  B=\lambda I+(1-\lambda)\alpha A.
$$ This is also a linear transform, so the image of a parallelotope is also a parallelotope (if the transform is non-degenerate; notice that it may be degenerate only if $\lambda=\pm(1-\lambda)\alpha$ since the complex eigenvalues of $A$ have unital absolute values; in this case $A$ should have eigenvalue $\pm 1$, and this may happen even in the planar case). This answers **Q2**.

As for **Q1** (and **Q3**), we need to check whether $B$ is an orthogonal matrix multiplied by a real number $c$ (provided that the polytope is solid). This is the case iff all eigenvalues of $B$ have the same absolute value, which reduces to the following two options:

1) All eigenvalues of $A$ coincide (thus $A$ is scalar, and the transform is a scaling); or

2) All the eigenvalues of $A$ are $e^{\pm i\theta}$ for some fixed $\theta$ (surely these two eigenvalues coinciding multiplicities). Thus $A$ acts as a composition of rotations in $d/2$ mutually orthogonal planes. This case cannot happen in odd-dimensional space (which answers **Q3**), but it sometimes happens in all even-dimensional spaces.

The phenomenon of the planar case is that for the plane there are no more options.

Comment: If object $P_1$ lies in a $k$-flat, and $P_2$ is obtained by rotation about an axis orthogonal to that $k$-flat (and then scaled), then I believe the similarity holds for convex combinations. For example, polygons in parallel planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Joseph: that's why I speak on the case when the polytope is solid (i.e. contains an interior point). But it seems also that you need not the rotation in this axis, but again some $k/2$ rotations at the same angle in orthogonal 2-flats.